# How to add a root or base url to css, javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I want something like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<%= BaseURL %>/css/main.css' />
```

on my master page and that BaseURL will work locally for default.aspx as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/main.css' />
```

and online as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.example.com/css/main.css' />
```

and in other pages like **example.com/page1/page.aspx** the css link should remain same,

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.example.com/css/main.css' />
```

and locally

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/main.css' />
```

That thing is needed in javascript link also...

I can't find any kind of solution or answer for this problem. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want the path to be relative , so try this :

```
<script src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("JS/jquery.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thats for JaveScript,

for CSS just write the path according to the masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

USe Url.Content as follows:

```
< link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<%=Url.Content("~/css/main.css")%>' />
```

that is assuming you have a folder css under your root folder